# My monero is stuck in the blockchain

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

Here is my hash: 7752063fb973b84030feca75b085ff7f38d1a6f9d857ac7df868b97d13d9048e

I need to retrieve my monero. How can I do this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The transaction was confirmed in block 1,281,619.  The monero probably remained locked for the typical 10 blocks, which is approximately a 20 minute wait time.  Once the 10 blocks passed, your monero was unlocked and was able to be spent.

If you don't see your monero in your wallet, then the node you're syncing to may not be fully synced.